# In spark 2.3.2, I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException when Dataset.count() is called

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am reading a dataset and [printing schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#printSchema--). It worked. 
When I tried to find the [dataset count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#count--), I am getting ClassCastException
as 
  `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection`

The same code works on Mac OS though. 
The exception is thrown in cloud vm running Linux_4.14.48

Please let me know if there is a fix. There is topic discuss about the fix 
in [Hadoop-14598](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14598) but that was for older version and I think Spark 2.3.2 might already has that patch.

There isn't much line of code and pasting it below though. The error happens when df.count() is called

    `val df = spark.read.format("own.format.dataset").load(sys.env("DATASET_ID"))
    val count = df.count()`

Comment: Could you please place the code snippet here

Answer (score 2):

I just struggled with this exact issue.  I was able to fix it by overriding the `hadoop-client` version (`spark-core` uses `hadoop-client` 2.6.5).  I added the following to my `build.sbt`:

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.9.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and as @Gregoire indicated it, it was linked to [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25694) in Spark.

But I did not add a fix in my code, just updated Spark to version 2.4.8 (bug fixed from version 2.4.6 and 3.0.0)

Moreover, the fix is not self activate, you need to set this property as indicated [in this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26530) :

```
spark.sql.defaultUrlStreamHandlerFactory.enabled=false
```

It worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is linked to hadoop-client 2.7, which is not linked to a specific spark version, so as suggested by @marteljn, you should bump your hadoop version.

If you cannot bump your hadoop client, then you can use this workaround :

```java
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory(sc.hadoopConfiguration()) {
      @Override
      public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
        if (protocol.equals("http") || protocol.equals("https")) {
          return null;
        }
        return super.createURLStreamHandler(protocol);
      }
    });
```

As suggested from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25694

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved after updating spark version to   2.3.0 recommend to use higher version to get this issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Use this after the Spark Context.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Application Name");
            JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
            URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration()) {
                  @Override
                  public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
                    if (protocol.equals("http") || protocol.equals("https")) {
                      return null;
                    }
                    return super.createURLStreamHandler(protocol);
                  }
                });
```